# Disk has been detached but dmesg throws xfs_log_force errors

Tags: xfs

I just replaced a bad Ceph OSD disk, everything went good except this one.

The previous bad disk was `/dev/sdh`, it has been replaced with `/dev/sdan`. But when I tails `dmesg`, I got constant XFS erros:

```
[Tue Feb 13 19:26:50 2024] XFS (sdh1): xfs_log_force: error -5 returned.
[Tue Feb 13 19:27:20 2024] XFS (sdh1): xfs_log_force: error -5 returned.
[Tue Feb 13 19:27:51 2024] XFS (sdh1): xfs_log_force: error -5 returned.
[Tue Feb 13 19:28:21 2024] XFS (sdh1): xfs_log_force: error -5 returned.
[Tue Feb 13 19:28:51 2024] XFS (sdh1): xfs_log_force: error -5 returned.
[Tue Feb 13 19:29:21 2024] XFS (sdh1): xfs_log_force: error -5 returned.
[Tue Feb 13 19:29:51 2024] XFS (sdh1): xfs_log_force: error -5 returned.
[Tue Feb 13 19:30:21 2024] XFS (sdh1): xfs_log_force: error -5 returned.
[Tue Feb 13 19:30:51 2024] XFS (sdh1): xfs_log_force: error -5 returned.
[Tue Feb 13 19:31:21 2024] XFS (sdh1): xfs_log_force: error -5 returned.
[Tue Feb 13 19:31:51 2024] XFS (sdh1): xfs_log_force: error -5 returned.
```

I have no idea to "tell" XFS that the disk is already gone.

I've came across the following discussions:

1. https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1192850
2. https://forums.unraid.net/topic/46288-xfs_log_force-error-5-returned/

The first one suggests to perform `xfs_io -x -c shutdown ...` prior to detaching the disk. I've tried this one and obviously the command cannot find the disk as it's no longer there.

The latter suggests to just reboot the system, which I cannot do, as this server is production.

I know that it won't affect the CEPH, but it's filling the log. Is there any way to fix/suppress the error?

---

```
Linux osd3 4.4.0-124-generic #148~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 3 07:26:53 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```